# How do I transfer videos I recorded on my iPhone 4 to my hard drive?

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 4 is constantly low on memory when downloading large Apps from the App Store.
I always get a message saying remove photos and videos to get space for new App.
I have been to Apple to sort out problem but did not work. The video are very important with sensitive info. How do I move these videos to my hard drive?

Answer (score 2):

This Apple Support article details how to transfer content to your computer.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4083

> Connect the iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch to your computer. iPhoto
>   should automatically launch into its import window with your device's
>   images and videos listed.
>
> Select the images and videos you would like to import into iPhoto,
>   then select the "Import Selected" option.

Answer (score 2):

I like [Image Capture](http://www.apple.com/macosx/apps/all.html#imagecapture) and [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) for getting files off (and back on in PhoneView's case) the iPhone. A lot of what I snap are screen capture and I'd rather just have a folder to dump the media so I can sort and archive it as needed.

Comment: And http://www.touchcopy.com/ seems to be the best alternative to PhoneView for windows users.

Answer (score 1):

This works just like importing photos off of your phone. When you connect via USB, iPhoto will launch and you'll be able to view and transfer your videos to iPhoto.

Comment: iPhoto does not launch by default. It depends on the computer's settings.

Answer (score 1):

iPhoto doesn't necessarily open when you connect your iPhone unless you have specifically set it to do this. 
You didn't mention if you were using a Windows or a Mac. 
If you do use a Mac, then image capture will do the trick. Head on into ur Applications folder and fire up image capture, and with the phone connected via usb you can see and import everything including pics and videos.

Answer (score 0):

You can either
1. Start Preview.app and import though it
or
2. Start Image Capture (in Applications/Utilities) and import through that application.

Answer (score 0):

hook it up to your computer via USB.  the ipod's internal drive will show up on your desktop just like any other drive. Move whatever you want from the ipod drive to your computer's drive.